# What is the correct way to save a list of items in a web form?

Tags: forms, algorithm, web

There is some form in a web form. It contains the list of items that use can edit, remove and change.

When the server receive the list of items, it should update existing items, create ones and remove the deleted ones.

I only know the naive and quite ugly approach:

1. When server receives the list of items from a client, it gets the actual list of items from the database
2. Pass round the received list of items:

   2.1. If element has the ID and database has the element with this ID, this element updates

   2.2. If this element doesn't have ID  or database doesn't contain element with this ID, this element creates
3. Delete all items, that were not in the received list (marked as deleted)
4. The updated list of items are returnded to the client (with new IDs), and client displays them

I feel, that there is more elegant solution, and, propably, established for this task.

Comment: And what have you done so far? Please append some code.

Comment: I suppose that the task is language agnostic. My current algorithm is described in the question, but I suppose that it is quite ugly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and i solved it like this: 
1-First when you load the page, create a list made up of id and data.
2-then the user fill the data.
3-those items that user doesnt fill should be deffault value.
4- then retrive the list from database and delete it and put the updated list
Hope this helps